# Object behaving strange

Tags: javascript, object

The problem is:
I expect the price of Animals[0] to decrease, but it also decreases the price of Cattypes[0]. How does this happen?

```
function Cat( name, size, price, colour, food)
{
  this.name   = name;
  this.size = size;
  this.price = price;
  this.colour = colour;
  this.food = food;
}
Cattypes = [];
Cattypes.push(new Cat("Dinky",20,150,"blue","fish"));
Animals = [];
Animals[0].push(Cattypes[0]);
Animals[0].price -= 140;
alert(Cattypes[0].price);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are passed by reference, not by value - `Cattypes[0]` and `Animals[0]` are **the same** object, **not identical** objects.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same object. Here is a quick and dirty way to create a clone of sorts:

```
Animals.push(Object.create(Cattypes[0]));
```

<sup>Won't work on olders browsers that don't support `Object.create`.</sup>

Now, if you do `Animals[0].price -= 140;`, `Cattypes[0]` won't be affected. But, because this method is relies on prototypes, if you change `Cattypes[0].price` without setting `Animals[0].price` first, `Animals[0].price` will also change.

Comment: Thanks , it works! Sadly I can't accept the answer for some reason, it says wait 5 minutes.

Comment: I tried ( JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( Array[number] ) ) ) and that works too, altho its a bit longer to wiret.

Comment: Yes `JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( Array[number] ) ) ` works too, andactually won't suffer from the glitch I mentioned in the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass objects to a function in JavaScript, the reference to this object is passed. Objects are not copied. When you add `Cattypes[0]` to your `Animals` array, the object is not copied. You're accessing the same object.

```
Animals[0].price -= 140; // here, Animals[0] is the same as Cattypes[0]
```

This is the anwser to the question "why does it happen". 
If you want to know how to workaround this, there are many ways you can copy an object. Please give a look at [this link](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/passing-objects-to-functions-by-value.html)

Comment: I believe ( JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( Array[number] ) ) ) fixes the problem ?

Comment: While it may work, I recommend you use either the answer given by @bfavaretto or something mentionned in the link I gave